# Why does XMLHttpRequest return two values?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to alert a txt file from my webserver in JavaScript.

This is what I have:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'example.com/maers.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var maers = client.responseText
  alert(maers)
}
client.send();
```

The problem is that there are two alerts:

1. The first alert returns an empty string.
2. The second alert returns the actual value.

I am trying to make the alert return only the needed value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the state actually is `READY`. Add to following to your callback:

```
if(client.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && client.status === 200) { }
```